# List task in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a tuple, let's say (2,5,8).

```
a = (2,5,8)
```

Each element of the tuple can take a range of values. For example, the first position can range from 0 to 4, the second from 0 to 6 and the third from 0 to 10. What I want to do is to keep fixed positions 2 and 3 and make a list with all combinations of the first element without the (2,5,8). Then, repeat the same for positions 2 and 3 and add it to the list output.

My desired output is something like:

```
[  (0,5,8),  (1,5,8),  (3,5,8),  (4,5,8),
 (2,1,8),  (2,2,8),  (2,3,8),  (2,4,8),  (2,6,8), .. ]
```

Any advice on how this can be efficiently done would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit: This tuple represents the state of a system. I want to write down a function that takes as input a tuple and outputs a list with all the possible states that the system can transition to. The tricky part is the dynamics of the transitions, which I described above.

Comment: What's your motivation and the range of likely values? It could be trivial to solve your example (20 iterations of a loop max) but the solution would be terrible if you actually needed like 20,000.

Comment: that's not an array, it's a tuple

Comment: I edited my question. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by efficient? If you mean it in terms of processing power, you should use 3 loops to append what you want to the list.

```
result = []
for i in range(5):
    result.append((i, 5, 8))
for i in range(7):
    result.append((2, i, 8))
for i in range(9):
    result.append((2, 5, i))
```

Or if you are using python3 or later versions of python2:

```
result = [(i, 5, 8) for i in range(5)] + [(2, i, 8) for i in range(7)] + [(2, 5, i) for i in range(9)]
```

Keep it in mind that in the end, you need 5 + 8 + 9 = 22 items in your list, so you can't write anything computationally more efficient that simple for loops.

Edit: For a more general solution:

```
base = (2, 5, 8)
bounds = ((0, 4), (0, 7), (0, 9))
result = []
for i in range(len(base)):
    result.extend((base[:i] + (j,) + base[i+1:] for j in range(bounds[i][0], bounds[i][1]+1)))
```

Comment: The (2,5,8) was just an example. In general, it can take any values, so I am looking for a more general solution..

Answer (score 0):

Although @Ariestinak gave a good solution, here is a generalized function you could use:

```
def getCombinations( a, b, c ):
    result = [(i, b, c) for i in range(5)] + \
             [(a, i, c) for i in range(7)] + \
             [(a, b, i) for i in range(9)]
    return result
```

Then to use it, all you have to do is:

```
a = (2,5,8)
getCombinations(*a)
```

Comment: Is there any way to generalize it for more than 3 elements in the tuple? What I was thinking is something like:
`for each element in tuple:
hold the rest of elements fixed
create possible actions`